# getting the following error when splitting test and train data in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, linear-regression, random-forest

Test_train split and please provide an explanation

[image: 1]

I tried to change the test_split from 0.2 to 0.4, but I do not know what singleton is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fafun.png)

Comment: Could you please attach the image within the question rather than having it as a link.

Comment: Its done. Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and actually ask a question.

Comment: Can you please provide more of the code - it might even be that you haven't assigned the X, y correctly or they are not of correct data type. Very difficult to say based off of what you have shown here.